# Detect/Alert When a Request is taking long to process in Passenger+Nginx+Rails Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have a non Enterprise Passenger with Nginx set up for Rails.

I am wondering if there is any way to detect if a request is taking `xyz` seconds. The challenge here is to detect/alert while the request is being processed, i.e. before getting the response.

The reason for the above scenario is because I want to know when a specific request is exceeding the obvious/expected time in which it should have got executed. Maybe it's stuck somewhere and requires manual intervention. Maybe there is no way that I would be receiving the response and I should look into it. (I am taking the extreme case here). But the process can't be killed directly unless the other requests are processed completely. Thus, an alert would be more than enough to help me out in this scenario.

Found few references such as :

- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/hooks.html#max_request_time_reached
  but that's more like giving passenger the responsibility to kill the
  process. It's not feasible in my case here since there must be other
  requests which must be on-going.

  https://blog.appoptics.com/monitoring-rails-get-hidden-metrics-rails-app/ But this is more like relying on rails to do the job. And it's not `while the request is on-going`.

Rails Version : 4.1.15

Any leads would be appreciated!
TIA

**Update (Clarifying the question in comments so that others can have a look at it too) :** 
@anothermh Let's take a simple case that, I'd like to make an API call which will eventually alert me that a *XYZ Request on Process PID is taking longer than the expected value. Please have a look at it*. I have the alerting system set up at my end, it's just that I want to be notified of this situation as well.

The reason for such a requirement of alert is that, once, we ended up in a state where Rails was making huge number of DB calls and stuck in the indefinite loop instead of making just one and moving ahead. This indefinite state caused the ActiveRecord queries (Graphs in Grafana) to spike up and that's how we got to know that something is stuck. But had we got to know the moment the request has started taking longer than the expected, we could have acted faster.

Comment: Do you use any monitoring tools like New Relic, Datadog or AppSignal in your app?

Comment: Look at the [`$upstream_connect_time`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_connect_time) and [`$upstream_response_time`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_response_time) variables.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you saying that if a client makes a request to your server and it takes longer than x seconds for Rails to process it, then you want to have nginx do...something? Or do you want Rails to do something? Or you want to have an alert raised so you can review it at a later time?

Comment: @spickermann We don't use any of them. Though we have Grafana set up at our end which shows the 2xx, 4xx, ActiveRecord timings/connections during that moment or the Queue status that we maintain. But nothing on the end where it says that 'XYZ request on Process PID has exceeded the expected time to get the response. Please look at it.' (in real time)

Comment: @anothermh I have updated the post with your queries. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the update, the answer is to use app analytics like New Relic. Are there free alternatives? Sort of, and they're all pretty terrible. (because doing this kind of thing well is complicated and expensive)

Comment: New Relic has a free, basic plan and you get the professional plan for free the first week when signing up for the first time. That might be enough time to find and fix the issue. Just saying...